# ifstream timeout very long when trying to open file on inaccessible network drive

Tags: c++, timeout, ifstream, network-drive

Think of a scenario where I start my application, do some work which includes saving network drive file paths, e.g. "\my\network\drive\file.txt".

Next time I open my application the network cable has been unplugged.

This results in a very long timeout time when trying to read files using ifstream. The timeout range is from 4 - 30 seconds and I don't know why it's different from time to time.

Code causing the timeout:
`std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream> ifs(new std::ifstream("\\my\network\drive\file.txt", std::ios_base::in));`

Any idea why the timeout is so long?

I'm running Windows 10 on a high-end computer.

Comment: Try accessing the file through Windows Explorer in the same situation and you will likely find that it takes just as long to timeout. This doesn't sound like a c++ problem.

Comment: True, that takes forever as well.